# Redirect to admin subdomain only when path ends with '/umbraco/'

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7, umbraco

I have a situation where our client runs their Umbraco based website with load balancing, and we have the following rule that redirects request to all of these servers to the primary domain "https://www.ourclient.co.uk".

This is the code for that redirect:

```
<!-- Canonicalize all domains to a single domain -->
<rule name="SEO - http canonical redirect" stopProcessing="true" enabled="false">
   <match url="(.*)"/>
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.ourclient\.co\.uk" negate="true"/>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^admin\.ourclient\.co\.uk" negate="true"/>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^01-live\.ourclient\.co\.uk" negate="true"/>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^02-live\.ourclient\.co\.uk" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^03-live\.ourclient\.co\.uk" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^04-live\.ourclient\.co\.uk" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.ourclient.co.uk/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

Now what I need to achieve is any request to https://www.ourclient.co.uk/umbraco/ is redirected to https://admin.ourclient.co.uk/umbraco/ but for the life of me I just can't get anything to work.

Any help towards a solution will be very welcome, as would any corrections to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a new rule.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="SEO - http canonical redirect">
          ... your old stuff ... but exclude the admin.yourclient.com/umbraco (!)
    </rule>
    <rule name="redirectUmbracoToAdminSite">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yourclient\.com$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^umbraco" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://admin.yourclient\.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```